# tinyMCE not working with jQuery Validation plug-in via javascript updates

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, tinymce

I have Validation working across a large form (I fire it several times before Submit to check sections of the form), and a tinyMCE editor working in 1 textarea. I want to move the contents of the tinyMCE iframe into the textarea before (that's the key here - before) the Submit button is pressed so that the contents can be validated in the section before Submit.

I've used `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` in several ways to move contents and then fire Validation before Submit. None work.  I am beginning to believe that tinyMCE contents cannot be moved by any Javascript, rather contents move only via the Submit button, but I don't see that stated anywhere.

In tinyMCE, I've tried `onchange_callback:` and `handle_node_change_callback:` to fire functions with triggerSave and other saving commands. I can get the contents of tinyMCE to validate when I press Submit twice (others have noted this peculiarity), but not in any other way.

Also, when errors are corrected in tinyMCE, Validation does not revalidate until Submit is pressed. It should re-validate in real time, as Validation is designed to do.

2 questions -

Anyone know how to move tinyMCE contents into the textarea without hitting Submit?

Does CKEditor allow updates other than via Submit, and if so, where's a tutorial or example?

Here's an example of code that is supposed to be triggered by tinyMCE's onchange_callback, but only triggers upon the second click on Submit.

```
function tinyMCESetValue(inst)
{
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()) {tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);}
// other save expressions that have been tried - with same results
//$("#selector").val(content);
//$("textarea.tinymce").val(content);
//tinyMCE.triggerSave();
//ed.save();
alert("some change"); //does not fire
}
```

In response to Thariama's comment, the above code is supposed to be triggered by the tinyMCEinit option of onchange_callback: "tinyMCESetValue",. I also have the following code in a JS section that does everything else correctly. The alert always shows 'undefined'. See any problem? Where else should I look/try? What tests can I do - I'm not getting useful info from Firebug.

```
if ($( "#sections" ).accordion( "option", "active" ) == 1)  //if the second Accordion section
{
    var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); //get the content from the tinyMCE iframe
        if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty()) //if the contents of tinyMCE have changed}
        {tinyMCE.triggerSave(true, true);} //put contents in the textarea
    alert("|" + $("#detailedDescription").val() + "|tinyMCEval");
    if (i == 7) {$("#detailedDescription").rules("add", {validCharsCheck: true});}
}
```

Comment: Please use some paragraph breaks (hit the `ENTER` key twice after a sentence). `:)`

Comment: looks like you should set a hook somewhere else to call this (your code looks fine)

Comment: @Thariama , I posted the other place in my code where I work with tinyMCE, if you care to take another look.

Comment: do you have more than one editor instance on your page? Are you sure "($( "#sections" ).accordion( "option", "active" ) == 1)" is true and gets called (the alert should appear)?

Comment: onchange_callback: and handle_node_change_callback:  work fin on my system, maybe a http://jsfiddle.net/ entry might be helpfull

Comment: @Thariama I have only one tinyMCE editor on the page. The only way to put content into the editor is in Accordion section #1. Additionally, when alert("|" + i + "|tinyMCEdirty"); goes in right after the if isDirty, it displays. The next alert for the value of detailedDescription displays undefined. It is as if it skips triggerSave() - for some reason, it has no effect here or from the onchange_callback function. Why would that be?

Comment: @Thariama I just discovered that when no content is in the editor (its clean, not dirty), the section validates, but does not advance to the next section. This means some other (interference with plug-ins?) problem happens with the code I posted above. I'll have to figure that out first.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem .
i changed **jquery.validate.js** file.

```
this.submit(function (event) 
{ 
    if (window.tinyMCE != undefined) 
    { 
        tinyMCE.triggerSave(); 
    }
    .
    .
    .
})
```

this solution only works for **tinymce**.

Comment: That's a good way, if you're brave enough to modify the Validation plug-in code. I wasn't. I ended up with JS that walks through the DOM and on the correct count of input boxes, fires triggerSave(). It works. Something is still mysterious about tinyMCE because the Validation plug-in cannot validate it in reasonable test conditions. I ended up validating that textarea in php. Thanks for your thoughts about another approach.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you are not getting client side validation on form submit time when you are using TINYMCE
i have one solution but this is not proper way but it work fine you can get all required validation on form submit time please check this code or example
***THIS IS CLIENT SIDE VALIDATION***
    
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany, new { @class = "required" })
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtAboutCompany)

**THIS IS JQUERY**

```
$("#BusinessProfile").click(function () {
    var aboutC = $("#txtAboutCompany").val()
    var pinfo = $("#txtProductinfo").val();
    if (aboutC == "" && pinfo == "") {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
        $("#bpform").valid();

        return false;
    } else if (aboutC == "") {
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("")
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("Please enter about company")
        $("#txtAboutCompany").focus();

        $("#bpform").valid();
        return false;
    } else if (pinfo == "") {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("")
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("Please enter product information")
        $("#txtProductinfo").focus();
        $("#bpform").valid();

        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#AC").append("").val("").html("");
        $("#PI").append("").val("").html("");
        //return true;
        $("#bpform").validate();
    }
    });
```

try it

Comment: The problem was with a textarea element. So in your case, do you have a textarea with id="txtAboutCompany" and class="required"  and the posted code puts up the error message if the textarea is blank? What else happens when the Validation plug-in runs the valid() or validate() methods? Thanks for your interest.